# Measuring Length cause wrong equations alignment

Tags: math-mode, macros, horizontal-alignment

Forgive my poor language and my unprofessional question but i need to understand more.

I wrote 2 definitions for a commands, the first command write the current X position and Y position BEFORE the equation box in a comment and the second command write the current X position and Y position AFTER the equation box in another comment, what i noticed after producing PDF that the equations with multi labels were not aligned at '=' sign and by removing the 2 commands, the equations aligned correctly at '=' sign.

Here is a snap form my Commands

```
\def\BEQN{\special{<!-- BEQN: "{?x}" "{?y}" -->{?nl}}}
\def\EEQN{\special{<!-- EEQN: "{?x}" "{?y}" -->{?nl}}}
```

and i am using these commands as the following:

```
\let\rendsplit@old=\rendsplit@
\def\rendsplit@{%
   \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{\BEQN\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}\EEQN}}%
  \rendsplit@old%
}
```

so, when i removed the commands `\BEQN`, `\EEQN` and `\hbox` with the outer `\vbox` from the previous part, equations aligned correctly and the previous part be as the following:

```
\global\setbox\z@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}%
```

Here is my full code sample

```
    \PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{hyperref}
\documentclass[final]{tc}


\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{chemarr}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{cancel}



%\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}

\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath,textmath]{preview}


\usepackage{multirow,array,eurofont,rotating}

\usepackage{etex}

\input{declaremath.tex}

\input{statement.tex}

%\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{0.05pt}

\makeatletter
\def\BEQN{\special{dvisvgm:raw{?nl}<!-- BEQN: "{?x}" "{?y}" -->{?nl}}}
\def\EEQN{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- EEQN: "{?x}" "{?y}" -->{?nl}}}

\def\BLBL{\special{dvisvgm:raw<g class="label">{?nl}<!-- BLBL: "{?x}" -->{?nl}}}
\def\ELBL{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- ELBL: "{?x}" -->{?nl}</g>{?nl}}}

\renewenvironment{gathered}[1][c]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{gathered}}%
    \fi
    \null\,%
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi \bgroup
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
        \spread@equation
        \ialign\bgroup
            \hfil\strut@\BEQN$\m@th\displaystyle##$\EEQN\hfil
            \crcr
}{%
  \endaligned
}

\let\lendsplit@old=\lendsplit@
\def\lendsplit@{%
  \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{\BEQN\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}\EEQN}}%
  \lendsplit@old%
}
\let\rendsplit@old=\rendsplit@
\def\rendsplit@{%
   \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{\BEQN\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}\EEQN}}%
  \rendsplit@old%
}

% Mark the equation tag with DVISVGM specials
\let\tagform@old=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\vbox{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- BVLBL: "{?y}" -->{?nl}}\hbox{\BLBL\tagform@old{#1}\ELBL}\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- EVLBL: "{?y}" -->{?nl}{?nl}}}}

\let\maketag@@@old=\maketag@@@
\def\maketag@@@#1{\vbox{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- BVLBL: "{?y}" -->{?nl}}\hbox{\BLBL\maketag@@@old{#1}\ELBL}\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- EVLBL: "{?y}" -->{?nl}{?nl}}}}

\def\irelop{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- irelop -->{?nl}}}
\def\ibiop{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- ibiop -->{?nl}}}
\def\cond{\special{dvisvgm:raw<!-- Condition -->{?nl}}}

\let\epsfig@old=\epsfig
\def\epsfig#1{%
  \epsfig@old{scale=1.36,#1}%
}

\makeatother

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}

\let\thejournal\relax

\def\addedcdot{{\color{blue}\cdot}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{gather}\begin{gathered}{E}_{\varepsilon }\dot{x}\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)=Ax\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)\mathbin{+}B\varphi \left(\vrule height 5.93326pt depth 3.39229pt width 0pty\vrule height 5.93326pt depth 3.39229pt width 0pt\right)\mathbin{+}{B}_{u}u\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right),\label{EEq1}\end{gathered}\tag*{$\text{(1)}$}\\[5pt]\begin{gathered}y\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)=Cx\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right),\label{EEq2}\end{gathered}\tag*{$\text{(2)}$}\end{gather}
   \end{document}
```

and this is my {tc} class file sample

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]

\ProvidesClass{tc}[2000/01/01v1.0]
\newif\ifcomments\commentsfalse
\newif\ifeqtypes\eqtypesfalse
\newif\ifshowkeys\showkeysfalse
\newif\iffinal\finalfalse
\newif\if@advance\@advancefalse
\newif\if@proofs\@proofsfalse
\newif\ifmega\megafalse
\newif\ifeditorial\editorialfalse
\newif\ifscientifica\scientificafalse
\newif\iftswj\tswjfalse
\newif\iftswj\tswjfalse
\newif\ifcpis\cpisfalse
\newif\ifretraction\retractionfalse
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{revtex4-1}}
\DeclareOption{comments}{\commentstrue}
\DeclareOption{eqtypes}{\eqtypestrue}
\DeclareOption{showkeys}{\showkeystrue}
\DeclareOption{final}{\finaltrue}
\DeclareOption{advance}{\@advancetrue\finaltrue}
\DeclareOption{proofs}{\@proofstrue}
\DeclareOption{scientifica}{\scientificatrue}
\DeclareOption{tswj}{\tswjtrue}
\DeclareOption{editorial}{\editorialtrue}
\DeclareOption{cpis}{\cpistrue}
\DeclareOption{retraction}{\retractiontrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twocolumn,twoside,nobalancelastpage,secnumarabic]{revtex4-1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%fonts%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[onlytext,lf]{minionpro}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage[amssymb,withamsmath,extraops]{minionmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minionamsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathdots}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{minionmath}
%\usepackage{minionamsmath}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage[raggedright]{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage{array,multirow,framed}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}

\iffinal
  \usepackage{hyperxmp} % For PDF/A XMP metadata
  \PassOptionsToPackage{pdfa}{hyperref}
\fi
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypernat}

%% BEGIN PDF/A PATCHS
%%
\iffinal
\forcsvlist{\listadd\my@metakeys}{Author, Title, Subject}
\let\old@pdf@addtoks=\pdf@addtoks
\def\pdf@addtoks#1#2{%
  \ifstrequal{#2}{F}{%
    % Very very very ugly hack to force setting annotation flags
    % to print, nozoom, norotate to make distiller happy when
    % creating pdf/a files.
    \old@pdf@addtoks{28}{#2}%
  }{%
    \ifstrequal{#2}{Color}{%
      % Another very very ugly hack to make sure that no url colors are
      % defined when hidelinks=true, otherwise the resulting PDF will
      % not validate when using CMYK color space.
      \ifHy@colorlinks%
        \old@pdf@addtoks{#1}{#2}%
      \fi%
    }{%
      \ifinlist{#2}{\my@metakeys}{%
        % We don't want to output some metadata keys at all, not even leave
        % them empty, so that Preflight does not complain about mismatch
        % between pdfinfo and XMP metadata.
      }{%
        \old@pdf@addtoks{#1}{#2}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\fi
%%
%% END PDF/A PATCHES


\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage{undertilde}
%\usepackage[single]{accents}

%\ifeqtypes
%\usepackage{resizegather}
%\fi

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Equation breaking%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\addedcdot{\cdot}

\usepackage{resizemath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% page dimisions%%%%%

%\special{papersize=602.3pt,11in}
\paperwidth 602.3pt
\paperheight 11in

\parindent 1.5em
\textwidth 500pt
\parskip 0pt

%\columnsep 1.5pc
%\topmargin -5pc
\columnsep 18pt
\topmargin -42pt

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-21.5pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-21.5pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Commands%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frenchspacing
\widowpenalty=10000             % No widow line at bottom of page
\displaywidowpenalty=10000      % Same for displayed text
\clubpenalty=10000              % No orphan at top of page
\hyphenpenalty3000
\lefthyphenmin3
\righthyphenmin3
\brokenpenalty 10000

\newcommand{\etal}{et al}
\newcommand{\un}[1]{\,\mbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\chem}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\bfchem}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{20pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%eqtypes%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\eqcomment}[1]{%                
%\AtEndDocument{ 
%\ifeqtypes
%  \newpage 
%    \onecolumngrid
%    \parindent=-30pt
%    \leftskip=0pt
%    \rightskip=0pt
%    \parskip=12pt
%    \fontsize{12pt}{13pt}\sffamily\selectfont
%    \begin{center}
%      Unknown Equation's Types
%    \end{center}
%    \par
%    \vspace*{5pt}
%         #1
%    \vspace*{4pt}
%  \fi
%}                    
} 

\newcommand{\eqtype}[1]{%
  \unskip
  \ifeqtypes
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{30pt}
    \marginpar{\framebox{#1}}% 
  \fi
}          
\newcommand{\shrink}[1]{%
  \unskip
  \ifeqtypes
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{40pt}
    \marginpar{\framebox{#1}}% 
  \fi
}
```

So, Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please post a full minimal example, that makes it a lot easier to figure out what exactly it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response @daleif. what i am trying to do is to measure the width and height of the equation exactly by measuring the start and the end of the equation in 2 dimensions X and Y then in another tool i get this information from the output comments and convert the equation into SVG. I made an edit to my question and wrote a snap form the equation.

Comment: That is still not very useful, we cannot compile any of that code without having to add stuff to it. Is this LaTeX, plain TeX ....

Comment: This is LaTeX project and i have cls file but i cannot post it here because of confidentially. sorry i cannot do more, what i need to know is the behavior of LaTeX in the both cases and is these commands affect the LaTeX behavior?

Comment: @MohamedSayed --- You don't need to share your class file, just delete irrelevant material to reduce it down to a short code that reproduces the problem. There are some real experts on this site, but none of them is psychic, as far as I know. Without sufficient information, there is a risk that your question will be closed.

Comment: @IanThompson forgive me but i cannot understand you, i am not expert in LaTeX, so please tell me what do you need from me now to consider it as sufficient information to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MohamedSayed: In its current form this question is basically not understandable is very likely to be closed as `Unclear`

Comment: If we can paste your code into an editor, compile it and see the same problem, then someone here can probably help you. If you just post snippets, so that we have to guess what other code is needed, then you are less likely to get help. See [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417) for more information.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i am trying now to clarify the question but i need to know your requirements to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MohamedSayed: Basically Ian Thompson wrote it 3 min ago

Comment: Ok i am now understand what you need and please wait for me i will come back with a full code

Comment: @IanThompson and ChristianHupfer: my question above had been edited with full code sample.